# ER_PARSE_ERROR: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== false

Tags: mysql

I want to check a checkbox value true or false and my query like this, but I'm getting an error here. Please help me to fix this issue. It's getting near checkbox value

```
    sql = `
SELECT    data
FROM      Job
WHERE     (? IS NULL OR
          JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.address') LIKE ? OR
          JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.customerJobNumber') = ? OR
          JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.jobId') = ? ) AND
          (JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.jobDate') IS NULL OR JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.jobDate') <= ?) 
          AND JSON_EXTRACT(data,'$.checkBoxValue')== false
          AND JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.status') NOT IN (?) `
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like in the conditions before you should only use one `=`. Also the value of the JSON_EXTRACT will be a string so you should compare it to a string:

`AND JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.checkBoxValue') = 'false'`

Comment: It's getting true or false. Then is it necessary to have '' ?

Comment: It depends on your json if you have `"checkBoxValue": false` you don't need the `"` if your json has `"checkBoxValue": "false"` you do need the `"`